# Requesting the correct Microsoft Graph Token

Tags: php, postman, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am currently writing some addons for my companies ERP system in order to be able to integrate various Office 365 aspects into it such as User, Calendar, etc. I have followed numerous online tutorials for token requesting and have gotten it to work both with Postman and in PHP. However I do not seem to be able to gain the correct token to access employee profiles in our domain. Every time I try to use the requested token I get

```
Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
```

Now I can already tell this is a scope issue, however I have tried all kinds of scopes,

https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All

etc...

But for some reason the error stays. I have given the App in my Azure Portal all needed permissions as far as I can tell. I am also requesting the token with our correct Tenant so that cannot be the issue.
If anyone has some pointers that would be great.

And yes the Postman token you can generate by filling out the oauth2 form yields no different results.

Answer (score 1):

And here I am again answering my own question, I am just stupid and the problem is that I was calling

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token
```

instead of

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Microsoft just don't give me a token if I am calling the wrong url ...